# Кракозябры в netty

Tags: java, netty

**Я только вникаю в netty, могу допустить серьёзные ошибки, не бейте тапками**

Я ради эксперимента написал чат, сервер и клиент.
Если я напишу сообщение на русском, оно будет на русском для меня, но для других это кракозябры.
Если другой человек напишет сообщение на русском, то вместо текста будет вопрос(-ы).

> Запись/Чтение строк из ByteBuffer'а

```
private ByteBuf buffer;

public String readString() {
    int len = readInt();
    byte[] bytes = readBytes(len);
    return new String(bytes);
}

public void writeBytes(byte[] bytes) {
    buffer.writeBytes(bytes);
}

public byte[] readBytes(int len) {
    byte[] b = new byte[len];
    buffer.readBytes(b);
    return b;
}

public void writeString(String s) {
    byte[] bytes = s.getBytes();
    writeInt(bytes.length);
    writeBytes(bytes);
}
```

> Часть кода из контроллера

```
 //chatArea => TextFlow[JavaFX 8]
 public void appendText(String text, String image) {
    Platform.runLater(() -> {
        Text textObj = new Text(text);
        if(!image.equals("null")) { //image не может быть null, но может быть "null"
            ImageView view = new ImageView(SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(ImageCache.getCache(image).getImage(), null));
            chatArea.getChildren().addAll(textObj, view);
        } else {
            chatArea.getChildren().add(textObj);
        }
        chatArea.getChildren().add(new Text("\n"));
    });
}
```

> Часть кода из клиента

```
public static void handleChat(String text, String image) {
    ChatController.getController().appendText(text, image);
}

public static void handlePacket(Packet packet, Channel channel) {
    {...}
    if(packet instanceof OutMessagePacket) {
        OutMessagePacket messagePacket = (OutMessagePacket) packet;
        handleChat(messagePacket.getMessage(), messagePacket.getImage());
    }
}
```

Скриншотов к сожалению нет.

Надеюсь этого будет достаточно.

**Update: + ещё код**

> Хандлер на стороне клиента

```
public static class ClientHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
        PacketManager.readPacket(Side.OUT, ctx.channel(), (ByteBuf) msg);
    }

    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) throws Exception {
        ctx.close();
    }
}
```

> Хандлер на стороне сервера.

```
public static class ServerHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
        PacketManager.readPacket(Side.IN, ctx.channel(), (ByteBuf) msg);
    }

    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) throws Exception {
        User user = fromChannel(ctx.channel());
        if(user != null) {
            handleDisconnect(users.remove(user.getName()));
        }
        cause.printStackTrace();
        ctx.close();
    }
}
```

> Чтение пакета (PacketManager::readPacket)

```
public static void readPacket(Side side, Channel channel, ByteBuf buf) {
    PacketBuffer packetBuffer = new PacketBuffer(buf);
    try {
        int id = packetBuffer.readInt();
        Constructor<? extends Packet> packetConstructor = packets.get(id);
        if(packetConstructor == null) {
            System.out.println("Unknown packet id:" + id);
            return;
        }
        Packet packet = packetConstructor.newInstance();
        packet.read(packetBuffer);
        switch (side) {
            case IN: {
                Server.PacketHandler.handlePacket(packet, channel);
                break;
            }
            case OUT: {
                Client.PacketHandler.handlePacket(packet, channel);
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (InstantiationException | InvocationTargetException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    packetBuffer.getBuffer().release();
}
```

Comment: Было бы здорово увидеть больше кода относящегося к Netty. Например, конфигурацию пайплайна. Есть у вас в нём какие-либо кодеки или один обработчик и всё? У всех пользователей системная кодировка одинаковая?

Comment: Я даже не знаю какая у них системная кодировка :D

Там только один обработчик (у клиента и у сервера), который "преобразует" ByteBuf в Packet.

Comment: Добавьте код обработчика к запросу. Пока подозреваю, что на у одного клиента JVM запускается с однобайтовой системной кодировкой типа cp1251, а у другого с кодировкой UTF-8.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev
Я добавил ещё немного кода, в вопросе под **Update**